# sqlalchemy empty datafrom while printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

engine=create_engine('sqlite:///Chinook.sqlite')

with  engine.connect() as con:
    rv=con.execute("SELECT * FROM Track WHERE TrackId >= 10 ORDER BY TrackId")
    dg=pd.DataFrame(rs.fetchall())
    print(dg)
```

Im getting an empty datafrom while printing.

Comment: For sql->pandas it is as easy as `df=pd.to_sql(query, con)` Is there any specific reason you are not using `to_sql` method?

Comment: Without a sample of your data the answer may as well be "no track has id greater or equal to ten".